# ScrollView not working. Need help or suggestions

Tags: qt, qml

I am having trouble getting the scrollview to work properly. I'm most likely missing something or I'm doing something totally wrong. This isn't my first time dealing with this issue either. The page contains a scrollview which has a stacklayout inside of it. My goal is to scroll through the stacklayout content using the scrollview. I tried setting the contentWidth and the contentHeight of the scrollview but that did not fix the issue.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12 // ColorOverlay

import "../../components" as NeroshopComponents

Page {
    id: sellerHub
    background: Rectangle {
        color: "transparent"
    }
    
    NeroshopComponents.TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: tabBar.buttonHeight
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        model: ["Overview", "Inventory", "Customers"]
        Component.onCompleted: {
            buttonAt(1).checked = true
        }
    }
        
    ScrollView {
        id: scrollView
        width: parent.width; height: 2000//anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.top: tabBar.bottom; anchors.topMargin: tabBar.buttonHeight + 10
        //anchors.margins: 20
        //contentHeight: height; contentWidth: width
        ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn////AsNeeded
        clip: true
            
        StackLayout { 
            id: dashboard
            anchors.fill: parent
            currentIndex: tabBar.checkedButtonIndex
            
            Item {
                id: overviewTab
                // StackLayout child Items' Layout.fillWidth and Layout.fillHeight properties default to true
                
                RowLayout {
                    id: stats
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter//Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop// <- this is not working :/
                    property real numberTextFontSize: 24
                    property string textColor: "#384364"////(NeroshopComponents.Style.darkTheme) ? "#ffffff" : "#384364"
                    property real boxWidth: 250//(scrollView.width / 3) - 20//scrollView.width / statsRepeater.count
                    property real boxHeight: 110
                    property real boxRadius: 6
                    spacing: 15
                    property bool useDefaultBoxColor: true//false
                    property string boxColor: "#ffffff"////(NeroshopComponents.Style.darkTheme) ? "#384364" : "#ffffff"
                    // Products (listed)
                    Rectangle {
                        Layout.preferredWidth: stats.boxWidth
                        Layout.preferredHeight: stats.boxHeight
                        color: stats.useDefaultBoxColor ? stats.boxColor : "#e9eefc"
                        radius: stats.boxRadius
                    
                        Item {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                        
                            Rectangle {
                                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                                anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.leftMargin: width / 2
                                width: 64; height: 64
                                color: "#e9eefc"
                                radius: 50
                                Image {
                                    id: productIcon
                                    source: "qrc:/images/open_parcel.png"
                                    width: 32; height: 32
                                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                                }
                            
                                ColorOverlay {
                                    anchors.fill: productIcon
                                    source: productIcon
                                    color: "#4169e1"
                                    visible: productIcon.visible
                                }
                            }
                            
                            Item {
                                anchors.right: parent.children[0].right; anchors.rightMargin: -(contentWidth + 20)
                                anchors.top: parent.children[0].top
                            
                                Text {
                                    text: "0"//"5430"
                                    font.bold: true
                                    font.pointSize: stats.numberTextFontSize
                                    color: stats.textColor
                                }
                    
                                Text {
                                    text: "Products"
                                    //font.bold: true
                                    color: stats.textColor
                                    anchors.left: parent.children[0].left
                                    anchors.top: parent.children[0].bottom; anchors.topMargin: 10
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // Sales (the total number of completed orders)
                    Rectangle {
                        Layout.preferredWidth: stats.boxWidth
                        Layout.preferredHeight: stats.boxHeight
                        color: stats.useDefaultBoxColor ? stats.boxColor : "#eff5ef"
                        radius: stats.boxRadius
                    
                        Item {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                        
                            Rectangle {
                                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                                anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.leftMargin: width / 2
                                width: 64; height: 64
                                color: "#eff5ef"
                                radius: 50
                                Image {
                                    id: salesIcon
                                    source: "qrc:/images/increase.png"
                                    width: 32; height: 32
                                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                                }
                            
                                ColorOverlay {
                                    anchors.fill: salesIcon
                                    source: salesIcon
                                    color: "#8fbc8f"
                                    visible: salesIcon.visible
                                }
                            }
                        
                            Item {
                                anchors.right: parent.children[0].right; anchors.rightMargin: -(contentWidth + 20)
                                anchors.top: parent.children[0].top
                            
                                Text {
                                    text: "0"//"17440"
                                    font.bold: true
                                    font.pointSize: stats.numberTextFontSize
                                    color: stats.textColor
                                }
                    
                                Text {
                                    text: "Sales"
                                    //font.bold: true
                                    color: stats.textColor
                                    anchors.left: parent.children[0].left
                                    anchors.top: parent.children[0].bottom; anchors.topMargin: 10
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // Ratings/Feedback/Reputation
                    Rectangle {
                        Layout.preferredWidth: stats.boxWidth
                        Layout.preferredHeight: stats.boxHeight
                        color: stats.useDefaultBoxColor ? stats.boxColor : "#fffbe5"
                        radius: stats.boxRadius
                    
                        Item {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            anchors.centerIn: parent
                        
                            Rectangle {
                                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                                anchors.left: parent.left; anchors.leftMargin: width / 2
                                width: 64; height: 64
                                color: "#fffbe5"
                                radius: 50
                                Image {
                                    id: ratingIcon
                                    source: "qrc:/images/rating.png"
                                    width: 32; height: 32
                                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                                }
                            
                                ColorOverlay {
                                    anchors.fill: ratingIcon
                                    source: ratingIcon
                                    color: "#ffd700"//"#e6c200"
                                    visible: ratingIcon.visible
                                }
                            }
                        
                            Item {
                                anchors.right: parent.children[0].right; anchors.rightMargin: -(contentWidth + 20)
                                anchors.top: parent.children[0].top
                            
                                Text {
                                    text: qsTr("%1%2").arg("0").arg("%")
                                    font.bold: true
                                    font.pointSize: stats.numberTextFontSize
                                    color: stats.textColor
                                }
                    
                                Text {
                                    text: "Reputation"
                                    //font.bold: true
                                    color: stats.textColor
                                    anchors.left: parent.children[0].left
                                    anchors.top: parent.children[0].bottom; anchors.topMargin: 10
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
                // TODO: show recent orders from customers, show seller's top-selling products, show customer reviews on seller products
                //ColumnLayout {}
            } // overview tab
            
            Item {
                id: inventoryTab
                // StackLayout child Items' Layout.fillWidth and Layout.fillHeight properties default to true
                Component.onCompleted: { console.log("InventoryTab width",this.width) }
                
                ColumnLayout {//GridLayout {//
                    id: productDetails
                    width: parent.width; height: childrenRect.height////anchors.fill: parent
                    Component.onCompleted: { console.log("ProductDetails width",this.width) }
                    spacing: 30////rowSpacing: 5
                    property string titleTextColor: (NeroshopComponents.Style.darkTheme) ? "#ffffff" : "#000000"
                    property real radius: 3
                    property real marginFromTitle: 7
                    property string textColor: (NeroshopComponents.Style.darkTheme) ? "#ffffff" : "#000000"
                    property string baseColor: (NeroshopComponents.Style.darkTheme) ? "#101010" : "#ffffff"
                    property string borderColor: (NeroshopComponents.Style.darkTheme) ? "#a9a9a9" : "#000000"
                    // RegisterItem to "products" table
                    //Product title (TODO: place both text and textfield in an item)
                    // If item fields are related then place them side-by-side in separate columns
                    Item {
                        //Layout.row: 0
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter// | Qt.AlignTop
                        //Layout.topMargin: 0
                        Layout.preferredWidth: childrenRect.width////productNameField.width
                        Layout.preferredHeight: childrenRect.height // 72 (child margins included)
                        Text {
                            text: "Product name" // height=17
                            color: productDetails.titleTextColor
                            font.bold: true
                        }
                        TextField {
                            id: productNameField
                            width: 500; height: 50
                            anchors.top: parent.children[0].bottom
                            anchors.topMargin: productDetails.marginFromTitle
                            placeholderText: qsTr("Product title")
                            color: productDetails.textColor
                            selectByMouse: true
                            background: Rectangle { 
                                color: productDetails.baseColor
                                border.color: productDetails.borderColor
                                radius: productDetails.radius
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // Product price (sales price)
                    Item {
                        //Layout.row: 1
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                        Layout.preferredWidth: childrenRect.width
                        Layout.preferredHeight: childrenRect.height
                        Text {
                            text: "Price"
                            color: productDetails.titleTextColor
                            font.bold: true
                        }                        
                        TextField {
                            id: productPriceField
                            width: 500; height: 50
                            anchors.top: parent.children[0].bottom
                            anchors.topMargin: productDetails.marginFromTitle
                            placeholderText: qsTr("Enter price")
                            color: productDetails.textColor
                            selectByMouse: true
                            background: Rectangle { 
                                color: productDetails.baseColor
                                border.color: productDetails.borderColor
                                radius: productDetails.radius
                            }                            
                        }
                    }
                    // Product quantity
                    Item {
                        //Layout.row: 
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                        Layout.preferredWidth: childrenRect.width
                        Layout.preferredHeight: childrenRect.height
                        Text {
                            text: "Quantity"
                            color: productDetails.titleTextColor
                            font.bold: true
                            //visible: false
                        }
                        TextField {
                            id: productQuantityField
                            width: 500; height: 50
                            anchors.top: parent.children[0].bottom
                            anchors.topMargin: productDetails.marginFromTitle
                            placeholderText: qsTr("Enter quantity")
                            color: productDetails.textColor
                            selectByMouse: true
                            background: Rectangle { 
                                color: productDetails.baseColor
                                border.color: productDetails.borderColor
                                radius: productDetails.radius
                            }                            
                        }
                    }                    
                    // Product condition
                    Item {
                        //Layout.row: 
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                        Layout.preferredWidth: childrenRect.width
                        Layout.preferredHeight: childrenRect.height
                        Text {
                            text: "Condition"
                            color: productDetails.titleTextColor
                            font.bold: true
                            //visible: false
                        }
                        ComboBox {
                            anchors.top: parent.children[0].bottom
                            anchors.topMargin: productDetails.marginFromTitle   
                            width: 500                     
                            model: ["new", "used", "renewed (refurbished)"]
                        }
                    }                    
                    // Product code UPC, EAN, JAN, SKU, ISBN (for books) // https://www.simplybarcodes.com/barcode_types.html
                    Item {
                        //Layout.row: 
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                        Layout.preferredWidth: childrenRect.width
                        Layout.preferredHeight: childrenRect.height
                        Text {
                            text: "Product code"
                            color: productDetails.titleTextColor
                            font.bold: true
                            //visible: false
                        }
                        TextField {
                            id: productCodeField
                            width: 500; height: 50
                            anchors.top: parent.children[0].bottom
                            anchors.topMargin: productDetails.marginFromTitle
                            placeholderText: qsTr("Enter product code (optional)")
                            color: productDetails.textColor
                            selectByMouse: true
                            background: Rectangle { 
                                color: productDetails.baseColor
                                border.color: productDetails.borderColor
                                radius: productDetails.radius
                            }                            
                        }
                    }                    
                    // Product categories
                    // Subcategories (will be determined based on selected categories)
                    // Weight
                    Item {
                        //Layout.row: 
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                        Layout.preferredWidth: childrenRect.width
                        Layout.preferredHeight: childrenRect.height
                        Text {
                            text: ""
                            color: productDetails.titleTextColor
                            font.bold: true
                            //visible: false
                        }
                        TextField {
                            id: productWeightField
                            width: 500; height: 50
                            anchors.top: parent.children[0].bottom
                            anchors.topMargin: productDetails.marginFromTitle
                            placeholderText: qsTr("Enter weight (e.g. 12 lbs.)")
                            color: productDetails.textColor
                            selectByMouse: true
                            background: Rectangle { 
                                color: productDetails.baseColor
                                border.color: productDetails.borderColor
                                radius: productDetails.radius
                            }                            
                        }
                        //ComboBox {
                        //    id: weightMeasurementUnit (default is kg)
                        //}
                    }                    
                    // Size
                    Item {
                        //Layout.row: 
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                        Layout.preferredWidth: childrenRect.width
                        Layout.preferredHeight: childrenRect.height
                        Text {
                            text: ""
                            color: productDetails.titleTextColor
                            font.bold: true
                            //visible: false
                        }
                        TextField {
                            id: productSizeField
                            width: 500; height: 50
                            anchors.top: parent.children[0].bottom
                            anchors.topMargin: productDetails.marginFromTitle
                            placeholderText: qsTr("Enter size")
                            color: productDetails.textColor
                            selectByMouse: true
                            background: Rectangle { 
                                color: productDetails.baseColor
                                border.color: productDetails.borderColor
                                radius: productDetails.radius
                            }                            
                        }
                        //ComboBox
                    }                    
                    // Variations (i.e. Color, Size options to choose from - optional)
                    // Product location (ship to and ship from)
                    //Product description and bullet points
                    Item {
                        //Layout.row: 
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                        Layout.preferredWidth: childrenRect.width
                        Layout.preferredHeight: childrenRect.height
                        Text {
                            text: "Description"
                            color: productDetails.titleTextColor
                            font.bold: true
                            //visible: false
                        }
                        TextArea {
                            id: productDescArea
                            anchors.top: parent.children[0].bottom
                            anchors.topMargin: productDetails.marginFromTitle                            
                            width: 500; height: 250
                        }           
                    }         
                    //Product images
                    //Search terms and relevant keywords (tags)
                    // tags must be separated with a colon
                    Item {
                        //Layout.row: 
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                        Layout.preferredWidth: childrenRect.width
                        Layout.preferredHeight: childrenRect.height
                        Text {
                            text: ""
                            color: productDetails.titleTextColor
                            font.bold: true
                            //visible: false
                        }
                        TextField {
                            id: productKeywordsField
                            width: 500; height: 50
                            anchors.top: parent.children[0].bottom
                            anchors.topMargin: productDetails.marginFromTitle
                            placeholderText: qsTr("Enter keywords or search term")
                            color: productDetails.textColor
                            selectByMouse: true
                            background: Rectangle { 
                                color: productDetails.baseColor
                                border.color: productDetails.borderColor
                                radius: productDetails.radius
                            }                            
                        }
                    }                    
                    // ListItem to "listings" table
                    //Button {
                    //    id: listProductButton
                    //}
                }
                
                //ColumnLayout {
                //    id: inventoryManager // inventory can be managed here and sorted too
                //}    
            }
            
            Item {
                id: customerOrdersTab
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Flickable?

Comment: I did but still couldn't get it to work. I just swapped the ScrollView with a Flickable and gave it a vertical scrollbar. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason why the `ScrollView` is not working for you is because your child `StackLayout` has `anchors.fill: parent`. This means the size of your child is already constrained, so it will never have a meaningful `ScrollBar`. Please review your anchoring / sizing.

Here's an example usage of `ScrollView`. Note that the `ScrollView` contains exactly one child. Note that I have not set the `height` of the child and allowed it to grow. Note that I modified the default policy making the `ScrollBar` always visible. Also note that I resize the `ScrollBar` to `20 pixels` and that I shrunk the content within by `20 pixels`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    ScrollView {
        id: scrollView
        anchors.fill: parent
        ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        ScrollBar.vertical.width: 20
        TextEdit {
            id: textEdit
            width: scrollView.width - 20
            text: `
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel sagittis tellus. Aliquam rhoncus laoreet mi at varius. Phasellus et nisl quam. Duis luctus porta quam, a vehicula erat aliquet sed. Quisque viverra erat risus, vitae congue libero vestibulum vel. Mauris vel interdum purus. Aliquam mauris justo, pellentesque vel sagittis ac, placerat nec enim. Nulla gravida non libero non mollis. Donec sodales ornare tincidunt. Vivamus mattis augue quis justo convallis, molestie tempus velit sollicitudin. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce ut nibh et odio mattis semper at sit amet elit. Nullam pharetra augue nisi, at vestibulum magna dignissim sit amet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc mattis congue magna at laoreet. Vestibulum tincidunt ante ligula, sit amet lacinia orci suscipit ac.
`.repeat(5)
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Here's an example usage of `Flickable`. Note that the `Flickable` must set:

- contentWidth and contentHeight correctly else you will not get a flickable action
- note the optional setting of a ScrollBar of 20 pixels and that I shrink the content by the same amount
- also note the optional setting of `clip: true`
- again I've only constrained the width of the child but not the height, allowing it to grow

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: textEdit.width
        contentHeight: textEdit.height
        clip: true
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
        TextEdit {
            id: textEdit
            width: flickable.width - 20
            text: `
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel sagittis tellus. Aliquam rhoncus laoreet mi at varius. Phasellus et nisl quam. Duis luctus porta quam, a vehicula erat aliquet sed. Quisque viverra erat risus, vitae congue libero vestibulum vel. Mauris vel interdum purus. Aliquam mauris justo, pellentesque vel sagittis ac, placerat nec enim. Nulla gravida non libero non mollis. Donec sodales ornare tincidunt. Vivamus mattis augue quis justo convallis, molestie tempus velit sollicitudin. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce ut nibh et odio mattis semper at sit amet elit. Nullam pharetra augue nisi, at vestibulum magna dignissim sit amet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc mattis congue magna at laoreet. Vestibulum tincidunt ante ligula, sit amet lacinia orci suscipit ac.
`.repeat(5)
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: I copied and pasted your code (well, just the Flickable component) and I changed my StackLayout's width to the Flickable's width, removed the anchors, but still, nothing happens. Thanks for your help though. I appreciate it.

Comment: Okay so I was able to get it to work by giving the StackLayout a height of 2000 and the scrollable area's height to parent.height * 2.

Comment: I found a better solution to my problem. Instead of placing a StackLayout inside of a ScrollView I've given each StackLayout Item its own ScrollView.

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I'm quite often setting `ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { }` on things like `Flickable`, `ListView`, etc, so, yes, it's worth checking your existing component if they have the `ScrollBar` attached property.

Answer (score 0):

You figured it out yourself already. I just add here what I've come up with. Because I didn't fully understand what you were trying to do I made different version of `ScrollView`s. As Stephen already said you anchor filled the `StackLayout` in the `ScrollView` which essentially makes it non scroll able as the `StackLayout` gets the same size as the `ScrollView`.

I came up with 4 solutions.

1. Scroll through a `StackLayout` via a `ScrollBar`.
2. Use a `ScrollView` with content.
3. Use a `ScrollView` around a `StackLayout`. In order to keep the height of the `StackLayout` correct it needs to be bound to the current item shown in the `StackView`. Otherwise it is as big as the biggest item in the layout.
4. The proper way which you came up with already to have `ScrollView`
   per item in the `StackLayout`.

These are all the solutions in one application.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls.Basic
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello StackLayout")

    component Content : Rectangle {
        color: "gray"
        border { width: 1; color: "black" }
        Text { text: index; font.pixelSize: 80; anchors.centerIn: parent}
    }
    // --- Solution 1 ---
    Item {
        id: frame
        width: 400; height: 300

        StackLayout {
            id: stackLayout
            anchors.fill: parent

            Repeater {
                id: repeater1
                model: 5
                delegate: Content {}
            }
        }

        ScrollBar {
            id: hbar
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
            orientation: Qt.Vertical
            size: 1.0 / repeater1.count
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

            onPositionChanged: {
                let i = Math.floor((hbar.position / hbar.size) + 0.5)
                if (i !== stackLayout.currentIndex)
                    stackLayout.currentIndex = i
            }
        }
    }
    // --- Solution 2 ---
    ScrollView {
        id: scrollView
        anchors.left: frame.right
        width: 400; height: 300

        ColumnLayout {
            spacing: 0
            Repeater {
                model: 5
                delegate: Content { width: 400; height: 300 }
            }
        }
    }
    // --- Solution 3 ---
    Item {
        id: frame3
        anchors.top: frame.bottom
        width: 400; height: 300

        TabBar {
            id: bar
            anchors.left:  parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            Repeater {
                model: 5
                TabButton { text: index }
            }
        }

        ScrollView {
            anchors.left:  parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: bar.bottom
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            StackLayout {
                currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
                implicitHeight: repeater3.itemAt(bar.currentIndex).implicitHeight

                Repeater {
                    id: repeater3
                    model: 5
                    delegate: Content { width: 400; implicitHeight: 200 * (index + 1) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // --- Solution 4 ---
    Item {
        anchors.top: scrollView.bottom
        anchors.left: frame3.right
        width: 400; height: 300

        TabBar {
            id: bar2
            anchors.left:  parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            Repeater {
                model: 5
                TabButton { text: index }
            }
        }

        StackLayout {
            anchors.left:  parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: bar2.bottom
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            currentIndex: bar2.currentIndex
            Repeater {
                model: 5
                delegate: ScrollView {
                    Content { width: 400; implicitHeight: 200 * (index + 1) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]